# AngularJS - Service with promise for common warning message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, promise

This is the first time I attempt to implement a service with promise and, so far, without success...

I'm implementing a SPA using AngularJS which can display an unlimited number of tabs at any given moment. There are tens of different tab types, each managed by its own controller.

At any given moment, any number of tabs can be open, including more than one instance of the same tab type (e.g. a tab to edit a user profile can appear twice, each with the information of a different user).

I want to implement a common mechanism that, whenever the data of a specific tab changed and the user request to close it, a warning message will be displayed asking to confirm or cancel the closure request.

The page to be shown with the warning message is activated through the following line within the Index.html file:

```
<div ng-if="Show_Data_Not_Saved_Confirmation_Flag=='Y'" 
     ng-include="'Pages/Data_Not_Saved_Confirmation.html'"
     style="z-index:1000000"></div>
```

and the page itself is:

```
<div id="Data_Not_Saved_confirmation_Page" 
     ng-controller="Data_Not_Saved_Confirmation_Controller" 
     style="position:fixed;top:0%;left:0%;min-height:100%;width:100%;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);padding:0 10px 5px 10px;z-index:10000;padding:20px 0 20px 0;vertical-align: middle">

    <div style="padding:20px;margin:auto;position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;width:450px;margin-top:-100px;margin-left:-100px;background:white;text-align:center;box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black">
        <font size="9" color="red">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </font>
        <div>
            <h3>
                Data was changed. Close tab without SAVE will cause data loss.
            </h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div style="width:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="height:60px">
                        <td ng-click="This_Page.Response = 'Proceed' ; Return_Selection()" style="cursor:pointer;background:mediumaquamarine;width:50%;">
                            <h2 style="margin:auto"><font color="white">{{All_Labels.Common.Proceed}}</font></h2>
                        </td>
                        <td style="min-width:10px">
                        </td>
                        <td ng-click="This_Page.Response = 'Cancel' ; Return_Selection()" style="cursor:pointer;background:red;width:50%">
                            <h2 style="margin:auto"><font color="white">{{All_Labels.Common.Cancel}}</font></h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>    

</div>
```

with its controller:

```
MyApp.controller('Data_Not_Saved_Confirmation_Controller' , ['$rootScope' , '$scope' , 'Confirm_Tab_Closure' , function( $rootScope , $scope , Confirm_Tab_Closure ) {


    var askForPromise = Confirm_Tab_Closure.getPromise();

    $scope.This_Page          = {} ;
    $scope.This_Page.Response      ;

    $scope.Return_Selection = function(p_Action) {
        askForPromise.then(
            // OnSuccess function
            function(p_Action) {
            $scope.somethingRight = p_Action;
            }
        )
    }

}]) ;
```

I implemented a service as follows:

```
MyApp.service('Confirm_Tab_Closure' , ['$rootScope' , '$q', function($rootScope , $q){

    $rootScope.Show_Data_Not_Saved_Confirmation_Flag     = "Y"        ; 
     var deferObject ;
     var myMethods = {
         getPromise: function(p_Callback) {
             var promise     =  p_Callback  ;
             var deferObject =  deferObject || $q.defer();

             promise.then(
                 // OnSuccess function
                 function(answer){
                     // This code will only run if we have a successful promise.
                     deferObject.resolve(answer);
                 },
                 // OnFailure function
                 function(reason){
                     // This code will only run if we have a failed promise.
                     deferObject.reject(reason);
                 });

             return deferObject.promise;
         }
     };

       return myMethods;

    }]);
```

and, within the tab's controller, the invocation of the service looks like:

```
MyApp.controller('Create_Edit_View_User_Controller' , ['$rootScope' , '$scope' , 'DB_Services' , 'Confirm_Tab_Closure' , function( $rootScope , $scope , DB_Services , Confirm_Tab_Closure) {

// Handle Closure Request by User... ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$rootScope.$on('Close_Tab', function (event, data) {

    if (data.Tab_ID != $scope.Tab_Forward_Info.Tab_ID) {
        // Not me !!!
        return ;
    }

    var l_Confirmation = Confirm_Tab_Closure.getPromise() ;

    dummy = function() {
        console.log("Promised executed!!")
    }

    l_Confirmation(dummy) ;

    Cleanup() ;

    LLF_Remove_Tab($rootScope.Running_Tabs , data.Tab_ID ) ;
}) ;
```

I'm getting an error message stating *"Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"* (the erroneous line is the `then` within the service definition shown above).

Comment: @SamuelLiew, whoever did the editing on this **6-MONTHS OLD** question, created 5 (I think) different versions of the edit, none of them contributing to the clarity of the original question. Additionally, I do not accept deletion of a _Thanks..._ as thanking is part of being civilized and part of my education. In short, there were 5 (or so) rollback for a single edit that I do not approve. Please (and if you wish), review the edit in details so you can get a better qualitative assessment instead of a quantitative (and superficial) one. Cheers.

Comment: Rollback revisions 3,4,5,6,7 are all yours https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49747606/revisions

Comment: There are several posts on Meta regarding the removal of "fluff", [this is the canonical one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778). Broadly, the community prefers technical writing here.